# Pattern matching for products of variables

Tags: pattern-matching, polynomials

What I am trying to do is very simple: In an expression that is polynomial in `x,y`, I want to check if there are products of the form `x^n * y^m` for any (integer) `m, n` including 1.
I tried with `FreeQ[expr, x^n_ y^m_]` but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: (1) `PolynomialQ[expr, {x, y}]` should handle this. (2) Questions of this sort are expected to contain an example indicating the issue.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake I wasn't precise enough. I want to use a function that will tell yield true if there are `x^n y^m` products with `n, m` not zero. `PolynomialQ` yields true even for the sole `x` terms whereas, I want in this case to yield false.

Comment: What would be the desired results for 1+x*y^2 or x + x^2*y?

Comment: Check `Coefficient[]`

Comment: For `x + y` it should yield false since there are no explicit products of `x^n y^m` for  `n, m` different from `0`. But for `x + y + x y + x^500 y` it should yield `True` since you have the terms of the aforementioned form, namely the `x y` and `x^500 y`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I found the solution:
For an expression polynomial `expr` in two variables, say `x, y`, if one wants to test if it contains explicit products of `x^n y^m` with `n, m` both different from `0`, i.e. terms like `x y`, `x^2 y`, `x y^2`, `x^2 y^2` etc, one has to do:
`FreeQ[expr, x^a_. y^b_.]`. The `.` included in the pattern takes care of the case `x y`, i.e. it includes also the case of `n = 1` and `m = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the coefficient of $x^2 y^3$ in $(x+y)^5$:

```
Coefficient[(x + y)^5, x^2 y^3]
```

If you want to see if that term is not $0$:

```
Coefficient[(x + y)^5, x^2 y^3] != 0
```

(* True *)

You may have to expand your function into a polynomial:

```
Coefficient[Series[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}], x^3 y^3]
```

(* -1/6 *)

and likewise....

```
Coefficient[Series[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}], x^3 y^3] != 0
```

(* True *)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as I state in my question, I want to it to return true for any `n, m` power that it is not zero. I don't want to check for specific powers.

Comment: Oh... then just use `CoefficientList`.